# Connect/Configure/Add VPN programatically in android above 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, vpn, openvpn

I'm working on android app in which I have add  and connect VPN programatically. I seem many questions-answers but all having not clear answer. Suggest me how to do this task. If any tutorial is available is always better.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programmatically connect the internal VPNs. Some apps (like OpenVPN for Android) provide interfaces to control them.